# I copied a link from a webpage to another area on the same page, now the title and link will not line up in the new area

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I'm updating a template, I copied this code from near the bottom of the index page (not the footer)  where everything is lined up as expected. I want to copy it to the near the top of the index page. When I copy the code to the desired area, the link does not line up with the text as described below, the number ends up higher to the right. I don't know where to start to fix this. The desired outcome of course is a link that lines up properly, e.g. Phone: 214-228-4000

```
<p><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> <b>Phone: </b><a class="nav-to" href="tel:2142284000">214-228-4553</a></p>
```

```
       214-228-4000 
Phone:
```

Comment: Problem resolved using this code:  <a href="tel:2142284000">Phone: 214-228-4000</a>

Answer (score -1):

you can easily put the phone number in span tag